# How to get scroll value of page in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get the scroll value of page so that I will able to enable a particular  component after scroll .

```
 <ScrollView
          stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
     {child1}
     {Child 2}
 </ScrollView>


handleScroll = (event: Object) => {
  console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
},
```

Here **nativeEvent** is not found inside event object. So is there any alternative methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this:

```
<ScrollView
          stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
     {child1}
     {Child 2}
</ScrollView>
```

```
handleScroll({ nativeEvent }) {
  console.log(nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
}
```